# Is there any built-in rails i18n support to translate attributes without call to the translate() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I am using the en.yml file to control the text on labels and buttons in my rails application with the following structure:

```
  helpers:
    submit:
      person:
        create: Create Person
    label:
      log:
        comment: Enter your comments here
```

In this case I do not have to invoke the translate method explicitly.  Is there a way to have similar translation on an attribute of the element?  I have searched for the hierarchy of en.yml without success so far.  So, I don't even know if it's possible.

Here is an example:

The view has:

```
<input id="person_name" hover_hint = "Please enter your name" type = "text" name="person_name">
```

Is there a way to manipulate the content of hover_hint attribute via en.yml without using translate method explicitly?

I can always create a symbol :hover_hint and then use t :hover_hint in the view for the value of hover_hint attribute.  But is there a way to avoid that - explicitly using the translate method- and use the en.yml structure instead as is done for labels and buttons?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious: how are you retrieving the values in the `en.yml` file without invoking the `I18n.translate` method explicitly in your views?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti: You just have to put values in the right hierarchy (shown partially below). The  problem is that I have not been able to find documentation of what all is inbuilt in rails for this.  Maybe a search of rails source code is warranted!
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      <model_name>: "expert match request"
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%a, %b %d - %I:%M %p"
  helpers:
    submit:
      <view_name>:
        create: <title for submit button with action :create>